# I have a loop whos condition depends on the booleen value of a function that the loop itself calls

Tags: javascript

```js
(async function() {
  try {
    let notAvailible = true;
    while (notAvailible) notAvailible = await checkAvailible();
    if (!notAvailible) orderProduct();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

will the while loop run until condition notAvailible is false, then run function orderProduct()? or will something unwanted happen?

Comment: Looks reasonable, but polling is inelegant, I'd prefer for the change to be pushed to *you* rather than having to request the current state multiple times. Maybe a websocket would help

Comment: The check for `!notAvailable` (which is awkward) is pointless; if that loop ever exists, the product is available. (Almost) all loops change *something* involved in their condition, otherwise no loop would ever exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this code may work, a few issues:

1. You have a problematic race condition. Let's say X is available as of the `checkAvailable` check, but before this code can go to `orderProduct`, X is no longer available because some other client ordered the available one. Then, `orderProduct` will fail. You appear to want to loop until the product is available.
2. The code waits forever for a product to be available. What if that never happens? A timeout would be a good idea.
3. The code relentlessly hammers the other end, constantly asking "is it available?" "is it available?" "is it available?" (like a toddler asking "Are we there yet?" :-) ). It should at minimum wait a bit, usually backing off in ever-larger steps before (again) giving up at some point.

Instead, have `orderProduct` send the order to the server (or database or whatever), and have **that** part of the system atomically order the product — and if that fails, say whether it failed because the product is not available or for some other reason, so that this code knows whether to retry. If the result from the server is "not available," wait a bit (with the incrementally-larger backing off logic) before trying again to place the order; and add a timeout.